# Is it a good idea to have a clock with a timed loop or is there a better way?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a clock I place in my GUI programs. Currently I use `.after()` to keep the clock updated. I am not sure if this method is the best option and I was trying to find a different or better solutions.

Is the way I am currently dealing with my GUI Clock the best way? Or is there something else I can be doing?

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import strftime

class MiniApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.my_clock = Label(self.master)
        self.my_clock.pack()
        self.status_clock()

    def status_clock(self):
        self.my_clock.config(text ="{}".format(strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
        self.my_clock.after(1000, lambda: self.status_clock())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk() 
    app = MiniApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is the correct way to do this sort of thing in Tkinter.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: Ok. I have been told in the past that a timed loop like this can be an issue but it was not the same kind of function as a clock. That is why I was concerned if this was also a problem.

Comment: Why are you updating it 5 times a second if you only display to a one second resolution? Also, there's no point in `lambda: self.status_clock()`, just use `after(200, self.status_clock)`. `lambda` is very rarely needed, and seems to confuse a lot of people.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I already mentioned that in another comment. I should updated my question. I was playing around with the timer and forgot to change it back on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct way. I see no reason to call that 5 times a second when it could only change once a second, though. Also, you have a lot extra gunk that you don't need. A little cleaner:

```
def status_clock(self):
    self.my_clock.config(text=strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    self.my_clock.after(1000, self.status_clock)
```

Comment: Ya I was messing around with the timer and forgot to change it back to 1000. Thanks for the info. I was hoping there might be different ways to accomplish the same task or even a better way but I guess I am stuck with this method :)

Comment: It seems like a great method to me; what do you have against it that makes you want a "better way"?

Comment: I had been told in the past on an answer I gave to a question that the timed loop I suggested to solve an issue the OP was having was a really bad idea. I am looking right now to see if I can find that comment. Anyway, Because of that comment it got me wondering if using `after()` here was a good idea or not.  I guess I was worrying about nothing.